# Management of NAN (Empty) values in a Pandas' DataFrame

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to drop all rows with more than one NAN elements in a Pandas' DataFrame using Jupyter Notebook. Does anybody have an idea how this can be achieved?

I am only able to remove all rows with NAN values using the following.

df.dropna()